# Foreach statement takes to long

Tags: c#, performance, linq, foreach

I have a foreach statement inside another foreach statement that is taking a really long time to iterate through. (There a  lot of records). Is there a way to simplify this code? Perhaps with Linq? Here is my code:

```
IList<SourceCounterPartyExposure_Limit> exposures = new List<SourceCounterPartyExposure_Limit>();

foreach (SourceCounterParty counterParty in limit.SourceCounterParties)
{
    foreach (SourceCounterPartyExposure_Limit exposure in counterParty.LimitExposures)
    {
        if (!exposures.Contains(exposure))
        {
            arExposures += exposure.ARExposure;
            mtmExposures += exposure.MTMExposure;
            volumeExposures += exposure.ConvertedVolume;
            if (maxTenorExposures < exposure.MaxTenor) 
             {maxTenorExposures = exposure.MaxTenor; }
            exposures.Add(exposure);
        } // if
    } // foreach
}// foreach
```

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly simplify the code:

```
IEnumerable<Exposure> exposures = 
  limit.SourceCounterParties.SelectMany(e => e.LimitExposures).Distinct()
```

Collapses both your loops and the if statement. You can `foreach` over that and run your code:

```
foreach (Exposure exposure in exposures)
{
    arExposures += exposure.ARExposure;
    mtmExposures += exposure.MTMExposure;
    volumeExposures += exposure.ConvertedVolume;
    if (maxTenorExposures < exposure.MaxTenor) 
       {maxTenorExposures = exposure.MaxTenor; 
}
```

That being said, its still a big enumeration, you aren't going to gain a *ton* of speed here.

Comment: Yup. The performance improvements will be relatively small, since what @EB is trying to do is implicitly expensive, but this is a good step forwards.

Answer (score 2):

Try a single loop over:

```
limit.SourceCounterParties.SelectMany(x => x.LimitExposures).Distinct()
```

That way you are (i) only getting distinct records back from the database and (ii) are allowing Entity Framework to translate your query into something that executes on the database.

You could also use `Sum` and `Max` to create a single query that would execute on the database.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible reasons to slow code is this condition:

```
if (!exposures.Contains(exposure))
```

If final order or items doesn't matter or you can sort them later, I would suggest you replacing it with

```
var exposures = new HashSet<SourceCounterPartyExposure_Limit> ();
```

If SourceCounterPartyExposure_Limit class has good hash function, than searches should be fast (close to O(1)) and it may improve overall performance of your code a lot.

Also probably you can change algorithm to run in multiple threads and then combine results. But not sure if this is appropriate for you.